# Invalid --keyring-migration-source option

Tags: mysql

Я пытаюсь установить MySQL (Ver 8.0.12 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)). Выполняю в консоли команду `mysqld -u root -p --default-file=...` и получаю следующую ошибку:

```
d:\Programs\MySQL\bin>mysqld -u root -p --default-file="D:\Programs\MySQL\my.ini"
Enter password: ************
mysqld: Can not perform keyring migration : Invalid --keyring-migration-source option.
2018-10-24T19:53:39.944570Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] d:\Programs\MySQL\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.12) starting as process 8184
2018-10-24T19:53:39.949553Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011084] [Server] Keyring migration failed.
2018-10-24T19:53:39.954386Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-10-24T19:53:39.955692Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] d:\Programs\MySQL\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.12)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Для чего вообще мне [эта миграция](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/keyring-key-migration.html) при первом запуске mysql? Можно ли как-нибудь отключить этот key-migration mode? Или как иначе исправить эту ошибку? Я пыталась выполнять в консоли команду с опцией `--keyring-migration-source`, но тогда получаю следующую ошибку:

```
d:\Programs\MySQL\bin>mysqld -u root -p --default-file="D:\Programs\MySQL\my.ini" --keyring-migration-source="D:\Programs\MySQL\lib\plugin\keyring_file.dll"
Enter password: ************
mysqld: Can not perform keyring migration : Invalid --keyring-migration-destination option.
2018-10-24T19:58:50.142426Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] d:\Programs\MySQL\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.12) starting as process 15164
2018-10-24T19:58:50.147956Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011084] [Server] Keyring migration failed.
2018-10-24T19:58:50.152461Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-10-24T19:58:50.153799Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] d:\Programs\MySQL\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.12)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

а файла keyring_encrypted_file, как приводится [в примере на официальном сайте](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/keyring-key-migration.html), у меня в директории MySQL нет.

P.S. Файл my.ini содержит следующие строки:

```
early-plugin-load=D:/Programs/MySQL/lib/plugin/keyring_file.dll
keyring_file_data=D:/Programs/MySQL/data/keyring/keyring
```

Также удаляла из конфигурационного файла эти строки, но та же ошибка (Invalid --keyring-migration-source option) появляется всё равно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь запустить сервер с параметрами `-u root -p`
Но это параметры для клиента `mysql.exe`, а для сервера `mysqld.exe` параметр '-p' означает:

> -p, --keyring-migration-password[=name]
>
> Password to use when connecting to server during keyring
>      migration. If password value is not specified then it
>      will be asked from the tty.

вот сервер и пытается провести миграцию

Параметр `-u root` для сервера означает запуск сервера от имени пользователя root, но в Windows это работать не будет